# Add options to right click menu of Mac Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

In Mac's finder, I want to right click on a file and hit one letter to automatically open the file in an editor (regardless of file extension).

For example, currently in Finder, I can right click a file and hit letter "D" and the menu will highlight "Duplicate" but I still have to hit the enter key to execute that action.  But in Windows I added a shortcut via the registry to edit the file with an editor of my choice just by hitting letter X.

Is that possible in finder?

Comment: Why right click to open a file in the first place? Cmd/O will open it. Cmd/D will duplicate it. This feels like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) What would happen if you wanted to Copy it? You 'one letter' solution would compress it instead, as that's the first hit for C.

Comment: that's why I'm asking if there is a way to modify the  menu so that one letter will load the file into an editor

Comment: You suggested Cmd shortcuts to Open (execute) and Duplicate the file, but, being a developer, I want a way to quickly Edit a file, without having to navigate through a long list of apps in the "Open With" submenu.  I had that single letter edit ability in the right click menu of Windows Explorer, and was hoping the Mac could be customized likewise

Comment: ohhh… actually there is a way, because the menu is also in the menu bar… sec...

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't realised this to start with, but the Open With menu is also in the Menu bar itself, as well as the right click menu.
Anything with an *actual* menu item can be key triggered - this is actually faster than the method you requested. [once the menu has loaded for the first time].

System prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts.

Add an item to Finder, then type `File->Open With->[app name]`* for e.g. 'File->Open With->Preview' and add a key command [this cannot be a single letter, it must have modifiers].
Then you can open any [appropriate] file in the selected app by simply selecting & hitting the key command.

[image]

*This seems to be one of those occasions where you do need to specify the menu hierarchy. It is not usually necessary as long as a command only appears once in the menu.